# How to get name of mounted disk from df command

Tags: bash

I'm running the following command to get the list of my mounted disk;

```sh
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            967M     0  967M   0% /dev
tmpfs           196M   21M  175M  11% /run
/dev/sda1        19G  3.9G   15G  22% /
tmpfs           976M     0  976M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           976M     0  976M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           196M     0  196M   0% /run/user/0
/dev/sdb         25G  8.2G   16G  36% /mnt/HC_Volume_4060368
```

and I need to assign this name `HC_Volume_4060368` to a variable. Since the number `4060368` at the end of that mounted disk's name could be different, I need a way to check it.

I used to get the name of the disk using the following command;

```sh
_dd=$(dirname /mnt/HC_*/*)
_dd=$(basename $_dd)
echo $_dd
```

result:

```
HC_Volume_4060368
```

However, there can be many disks with similar names that starts with `HC_Volume_*` inside `/mnt/` folder such as `HC_Volume_xxxxxxx` but only one of them is actually mounted and I need to find the name of that mounted disk only. I guess only way to find this is by checking through `df` command but I couldn't find a way to extract the bare name of disk from that command's result.

How can I do this?

Comment: `/mnt/HC_Volume_4060368` is a mount point.

Comment: @Cyrus Which means?

Comment: @MarryJane, it is not clear to me what is your desired output. Also, you refer to more lines of the form `HC_Volume_xxxxxxx`: please put some other line like this in your first chunk of code and tell us what you want to do with it.

Comment: @Cyrus is just saying that `/mnt/HC_Volume_4050368` is the mount point, not the disc; this means that the corresponding disk (`/dev/sdb`) is mounted already.

Comment: I just want to get the name the mount point that comes after `/mnt/` from the result of `df` command and assign it into a variable. In this case, it should be `HC_Volume_4060368` but the number that comes after `HC_Volume_` can be different so I need a general solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inspect the output of the `mount` command to get a list of currently mounted filesystems.  The output consists of one line per mount of the format:

```
<device> on <mountpoint> type <fstype> (<options>)
```

If you're looked for a *mounted* volume that matches `HC_Volume_*`, you could do this:

```
mountpoint=$(mount | awk '$3 ~ /HC_Volume_/ {print $3}')
volname=${mountpoint##*/}
```

If there are multiple *mounted* volumes with matching names, you would need to decide how to handle that.

Comment: It works, thanks! Can we do it with `df` as well instead of `mount` or does it even matter?

Comment: The output of `df` is less amendable to automated parsing. I would prefer `mount` for this task.